A variant of Seetapun's theorem
Let $X \in 2^{\omega} \setminus \Delta^1_1$ (i.e., $X$ is not hyperarithmetical) and $A \subseteq \omega$. Must there exist $B \in [A]^{\omega} \cup [\omega \setminus A]^{\omega}$ such that no infinite subset of $B$ computes $X$?

Yes, this is a consequence of Solovay's results on computably encodable sets.  Since $X$ is not hyperarithmetical, there is some infinite set $C$ such that no subset of $C$ computes $X$.  If $C \cap A$ is infinite, let $B = C \cap A$.  Otherwise, let $B = C \setminus A$.  Then every subset of $B$ is a subset of $C$, and thus does not compute $X$.
